# Set form text field values after the form submission with ant design in react

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-props, ant-design-pro, react-state

I need to change the form text field value after submitting it. I used https://ant.design/components/form/ ant design to create the form.

I have tried the following code inside the form onSubmit method.

```
this.props.form.setFieldsValue({ count: pasId});
```

Here count is the getFieldDecorator's id. But the count field value doesn't change to value of pasId variable when I checked as follows.

`console.log(values.count);`

So where I could get wrong and how to set the form field value after the form values get submitted to the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to be using `fieldDecorator`s, as I can see in the source code for the example for `setFieldsValue`.

https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-coordinated

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/form/demo/coordinated.md

Comment: My problem is still unable to change the values.count to pasId variable value. Only I could change the text field value @Kevin Lindsay